# Modern mathematics for dummies

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, differential-geometry, book-recommendation

I have poor university mathematical education, but Math fascinates me, so I decided to educate myself for a bit. I know there is a dozen modern mathematical fields I know nearly nothing about like differential and abstract topology, differential and abstract geometry, homological algebra, Lie groups etc.

I am looking for some books, but not deep textbooks, something like "for dummies" which will spell these fields out, with not very many proofs, not very many abstract symbols. I know there's Roger Penrose — The Road to Reality, the first half of which covers modern differential geometry very well, I know there's Charles Nash, Siddhartha Sen — Topology and Geometry for Physicists, which tries to cover the beginning of abstract topology. Is there anything like that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get started with *Topology without Tears* found online [here](http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/~filip/aidt/topbook.pdf).

And sometimes I personally find it fun to soak up smattering of knowledge from biography. So perhaps, you can start with bios of Zariski or Felix Klein?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this topology books
1-Topology General-Serie Shawn 
2-Topology-REA Problem Solver

Comment: Could you include some information, in the answer, on how these books are an answer to the OP's question?

Comment: Topology for dummies looks like a good book, even easier than Topology without Tears, Topology without Tears makes me wanna bang my head against the wall ,to my brain drop out. Well atleast I am not crying  Schaum’s Outline on it is good too

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Topology-Problem-Solver-Solvers-Solution/dp/0878919252/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&qid=1618493086&refinements=p_27%3ARea&s=books&sr=1-1

Comment: Dr. Mark Ryan has NOT yet written a book on Topology for Dummies for Wiley publishings                                                           
                                                                             
                    https://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Dummies-Mark-Ryan/dp/1119181550/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&qid=1618493199&refinements=p_lbr_books_series_browse-bin%3AFor+Dummies&s=books&sr=1-1